# Latest update broke my custom login CSS

Tags: customization, login

After updating to WP 5.3 I am having trouble removing the border that was added on the login page.
I have managed to remove it everywhere, except when I am entering the wrong password/account name, I am displayed with part of the default styling, but when inspecting the page the CSS path and names are still the same, but my custom CSS is not applied here? Is this because of the shaking that uses javascript to shake the login box, which causes the CSS to be removed?

First image shows the login page styled correctly, and second image shows after the error. You can se a border around it, and the wrong styling on the Password box:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend submitting a link to your login page so we can look at it directly, but from your screenshot, it looks like an outline has been added.

I would recommend adding a CSS rule that removes the outline. See below as an example of the CSS you can use; however, you will need to adjust the selector to fit your site.

```
.login_container{
   outline: 0 !important;
}
```